Does אַגְרָא (Avot 5:23) translate better as פְּרָס or שְׂכַר?
I believe (based on Rambam on Avot 1:3) that פְּרָס translates better as "a present given in grace as an unearned gift, rather than as wages", whereas שְׂכַר is more akin to what one deserves for one's work; wages; earnings.
It would seem natural then, given the context of Avot 5:23, that אַגְרָא translates better as שְׂכַר, as it is commesurate with the effort.

בֶּן הֵא הֵא אוֹמֵר, לְפוּם צַעֲרָא אַגְרָא:
Ben He He said: According to the labor is the [?].

But maybe not. Does anyone have proof (or disproof, or an alternative) to my theory?
As an aside, I am curious to know if there are any other "categories of reward", and what the differences between them are.

https://he.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%92%D7%A8%D7%94

@Harel13 thank you. I should use the wiktionary more. I haven't really ever been directly recommended - it's for all to edit like any wiki, right? Do you find it overall trustworthy and useful?

When it's sourced it's generally trustworthy, as is the case here.

@Harel13 fair enough. Well, it would make a perfect answer. I've already given you a checkmark this week, how about another?

According to the sources brought by Wiktionary, שכר is the preferable translation for אגרא as well as its other Semitic counterparts (and for this reason Modern Hebrew uses אגרה, usually as a word referring to tolls and fees).
